# How can I start MS Office Word from .NET without Add-ins?

Tags: c#, ms-office

I'm using MS Office 2003 PIA to create a MS Word document from c#.

```
ApplicationClass officeApplication = new ApplicationClass();
```

Is there any way to specify that I don't want any office add-ins to be loaded using this method?

EDIT:

I know that one can do this via command line so I'm pretty sure there must be a way to do it from code:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office11\Winword.exe" /a
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code unload the AddIns

```
officeApplication.AddIns.Unload(false);
```

Edited:
When you need to mix the process start and possibility to use the office "application" interface, you need the **Marshal.GetActiveObject** command. 
**Example :**

```
        //startup without plugins
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(
            @"Winword.exe",
            @"/a");
        //give a time for startup
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        //attach to office
        Application officeApplication = (Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
```

Comment: Is there a way to stop them loading in the first place? I'm trying to avoid the startup performance hit when customers have lots of add-ins. I need to start word quickly, do some processing and close it again.

Comment: are you able to use this line of code to open, say a word document from a sharepoint location? for example System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("winword.exe"
"https:\\sharepoint.com\documentlibrary\Winword.exe", username, password, domain)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(
  @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office11\Winword.exe", 
  @"/a");
```

Comment: Thanks, but I specifically want to use the PIA as above.

Comment: are you able to use this line of code to open, say a word document from a sharepoint location? for example System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("winword.exe",
"https:\\sharepoint.com\documentlibrary\Winword.exe", username, password, domain);

Comment: You cannot use Process with a URL.  However sharepoint url's do map to actual folders.  I see your url includes https.  I am not an expert in sharepoint, but I think that means the folder is encrypted.  If that is correct you will need a decryption key.